# `Don't talk to me': - How to render apostrophe within single quotation?

Tags: characters, zotero

I have issues rendering with LaTeX `` `Don't talk to me': ``

I have this title as bibliographic entry in Zotero (it starts exactly like that). LaTeX & Biber complain when I try to parse the `.bib` file with that entry. How could I correct the entry in Zotero to avoid problems by playing safe with encoding problems (but also to keep Zotero compatible with other apps)?

Comment: In most fonts/encodings there is no difference between an apostrophe and a close quote, what difference do you want?

Comment: Use `csquotes`?

Comment: Using `csquotes` would be a good logical indicator to use; separately, I think OP wants 'straight' quotes.

Comment: In unicode, point 0027 is an apostrophe, but the 2019 is "to be preferred"; 2018 and 2019 are left and right single quotes.  See http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0000.pdf

Comment: @AndrewSwann To be precise, 0027 `'` is everything you want it to be (aka “the typewriter apostrophe”): apostrophe, single quotation mark, arcminute, prime, etc. The 2019 apostrophe is typographically the correct one `’` and it is also the closing single quotation mark in English. the `'` is the `"` version of `“` and `”` (minus the apostrophe part).

Comment: I have this title as bibliographic entry in Zotero (it starts exactly like that). Latex & Biber complain when I try to parse the .bib file with that entry. How could I correct the entry in Zotero to avoid problems (but also to keep Zotero compatible with others apps)?

Comment: If you are using `biber`, that means you are using `biblatex`, which means you could (perhaps even should) use `title = {\mkbibquote{Don't talk to me}},` and `sortttile = {Don't talk to me},`.  In English texts, it is important to nest quotation marks correctly, and `biblatex` knows how to do that if you 'code' your entries correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is likely that Zotero includes the left quote when building the cite key, so you're probably getting a `Bibtex` entry like:

```
@article{test_`dont_2003,
series = {n/a},
title = {{`Don't} talk to me'},
volume = {1},
abstract = {Testing},
number = {2},
journal = {any},
author = {test, test},
month = jan,
year = {2003},
pages = {3}
}
```

So you need to work out a way to force the cite key to be something like `@article{test_dont_2003,`. This link provides details on how to control how Zotero builds a cite key: http://www.curiousjason.com/zoterotobibtex.html

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I wrote a BibTex translator that solves most of my problems while exporting from Zotero into Latex. You find it [here](https://github.com/fraba/translators/blob/master/BibTeX.js)